# Sum value across dynamic date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I am trying to sum totals based on a monthly period for each event - with the monthly time windows based on the first occurrence of each event.

For instance, I have the following three events and the date ranges for which I am trying to sum a value:

```
Catastrophe         MonthNumber  BeginDate  EndDate
Hurricane Barry     1            7/16/2019  8/16/2019
Hurricane Barry     2            8/16/2019  9/13/2019
Hurricane Dorian    1            9/4/2019   9/13/2019
Hurricane Florence  1            9/15/2018  10/15/2018
Hurricane Florence  2            10/15/2018 11/15/2018
Hurricane Florence  3            11/15/2018 12/15/2018
Hurricane Florence  4            12/15/2018 1/15/2019
Hurricane Florence  5            1/15/2019  2/15/2019
Hurricane Florence  6            2/15/2019  3/15/2019
Hurricane Florence  7            3/15/2019  4/15/2019
Hurricane Florence  8            4/15/2019  5/15/2019
Hurricane Florence  9            5/15/2019  6/15/2019
Hurricane Florence  10           6/15/2019  7/15/2019
Hurricane Florence  11           7/15/2019  8/15/2019
Hurricane Florence  12           8/15/2019  9/13/2019
```

For Hurricane Barry, I am looking to have two records:

- Period 7/16/2010 to 8/15/2019
- Period 8/16/2019 to 9/13/2019 ( would be 9/15 but I'm asking this question 9/13 )

For Hurricane Dorian, we would have only one monthly summary:

- Period 9/4/2019 to 9/13/2019 ( date of posting )

And since Hurricane Florence happened on 9/15/2018 - we now have 12 monthly summaries I am trying to generate.

I thought this TSQL would give me the monthly summaries but this query is not returning any data:

```
SELECT r.Catastrophe,
       r.MonthNumber,
       SUM ( b.Amount )
FROM TransactionTable AS b
    INNER JOIN #CatastropheDateRanges AS r ON r.Catastrophe = b.Catastrophe
WHERE r.BeginDate >= b.TransactionDate
      AND r.EndDate < b.TransactionDate
GROUP BY r.Catastrophe,
         r.MonthNumber;
```

Below is what I would like my result set to look like:

```
Catastrophe         Month Number  Total
Hurricane Barry     1             $300.00
Hurricane Barry     2             $350.00
Hurricane Dorian    1             $700.00
Hurricane Florence  1             $300.00
Hurricane Florence  2             $1,000.00
Hurricane Florence  3             $250.00
Hurricane Florence  4             $350.00
```

Sample data to get the data set:

```
CREATE TABLE #CatastropheDateRanges
(
    Catastrophe VARCHAR (60),
    MonthNumber INT,
    BeginDate DATE,
    EndDate DATE
);
INSERT INTO #CatastropheDateRanges
VALUES
('Hurricane Barry', 1, N'2019-07-16', N'2019-08-16'),
('Hurricane Barry', 2, N'2019-08-16', N'2019-09-13'),
('Hurricane Dorian', 1, N'2019-09-04', N'2019-09-13'),
('Hurricane Florence', 1, N'2018-09-15', N'2018-10-15'),
('Hurricane Florence', 2, N'2018-10-15', N'2018-11-15'),
('Hurricane Florence', 3, N'2018-11-15', N'2018-12-15'),
('Hurricane Florence', 4, N'2018-12-15', N'2019-01-15'),
('Hurricane Florence', 5, N'2019-01-15', N'2019-02-15'),
('Hurricane Florence', 6, N'2019-02-15', N'2019-03-15'),
('Hurricane Florence', 7, N'2019-03-15', N'2019-04-15'),
('Hurricane Florence', 8, N'2019-04-15', N'2019-05-15'),
('Hurricane Florence', 9, N'2019-05-15', N'2019-06-15'),
('Hurricane Florence', 10, N'2019-06-15', N'2019-07-15'),
('Hurricane Florence', 11, N'2019-07-15', N'2019-08-15'),
('Hurricane Florence', 12, N'2019-08-15', N'2019-09-13');


SELECT *
FROM #CatastropheDateRanges;


CREATE TABLE #TransactionTable
(
    Catastrophe VARCHAR (50),
    TransactionDate DATE,
    TransactionAmount DECIMAL (19, 4)
);

INSERT INTO #TransactionTable
(
    Catastrophe,
    TransactionDate,
    TransactionAmount
)
VALUES
('Hurricane Barry', '20190716', 100.00),
('Hurricane Barry', '20190720', 150.00),
('Hurricane Barry', '20190725', 50.00),
('Hurricane Barry', '20190825', 350.00),
('Hurricane Dorian', '20190910', 350.00),
('Hurricane Dorian', '20190911', 350.00),
('Hurricane Florence', '20180920', 100.00),
('Hurricane Florence', '20180922', 200.00),
('Hurricane Florence', '20181022', 500.00),
('Hurricane Florence', '20181023', 500.00),
('Hurricane Florence', '20181115', 100.00),
('Hurricane Florence', '20181116', 150.00),
('Hurricane Florence', '20181216', 350.00);

SELECT *
FROM #TransactionTable;

DROP TABLE #TransactionTable;
DROP TABLE #CatastropheDateRanges;
```

Any suggestions on how I can get these monthly summaries based on the begin and end date from my #CatastropheDateRanges table?

Comment: Would you please edit your question to (1) Show sample data for the `TransationTable` table (2) Show your expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as concerns, you just need to invert the dates comparisons.

Change:

```
WHERE r.BeginDate >= b.TransactionDate AND r.EndDate < b.TransactionDate
```

To:

```
WHERE r.BeginDate <= b.TransactionDate AND r.EndDate > b.TransactionDate
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=e3f86b444b26b171ffa487151587b82c)**:

```
Catastrophe        | MonthNumber | (No column name)
:----------------- | ----------: | :---------------
Hurricane Barry    |           1 | 300.0000        
Hurricane Barry    |           2 | 350.0000        
Hurricane Dorian   |           1 | 700.0000        
Hurricane Florence |           1 | 300.0000        
Hurricane Florence |           2 | 1000.0000       
Hurricane Florence |           3 | 250.0000        
Hurricane Florence |           4 | 350.0000
```

Comment: Ugh... Can't believe I missed that.  Thanks for your help in getting me to the right answer!