# SQL: 21 day avg sale in front of date for a week

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

What I need is, 21 days of sales from that date populated in front of SKU.

e.g I am pulling data for 1 week at SKU, day level and I want to populate average 21 day sale from that day in front of that SKU. Desired output:

```
Date      SKU Name  Avg_21_day_sale
1-1-2023  SKU1  avgt21sale 21 (this avg sale is 21 days before this date)
1-1-2023  SKU2  avgt21sale 66 (this avg sale is 21 days before this date)
1-2-2023  SKU1  avgt21sale 77 (this avg sale is 21 days before this date)
1-2-2023  SKU2  avgt21sale 99 (this avg sale is 21 days before this date)
```

I tried something like [Sum value across dynamic date range - StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57929485/174777) thread.

Also tried:

```sql
select 
    date, sku
    , avg(sale) over (partition by sku range between date- 21 and date) avg_sale_21_day
from table 
group by 1,2
```

Expected output:

```
Date      SKU Name  Avg_21_day_sale
1-1-2023  SKU1  avgt21sale 21 (this avg sale is 21 days before this date)
1-1-2023  SKU2  avgt21sale 66 (this avg sale is 21 days before this date)
1-2-2023  SKU1  avgt21sale 77 (this avg sale is 21 days before this date)
1-2-2023  SKU2  avgt21sale 99 (this avg sale is 21 days before this date)
```

Comment: Both sample data and the (matching) expected result would make this clearer. (I.e. a [mcve].)

Comment: Also add a tag for the dbms you're using.

Answer (score 0):

```
select A.date,A.sku,B.Avg_21_day_sale

from

(

select date,sku

from table

)A

left join

(
select *

from

(

select sku,sum(sales)/21 as Avg_21_day_sale

from table

where date between date-20 and date

group by sku

)

)B

on A.sku = B.sku
```